# Get network usage for ethernet cards with MAC addresses

Tags: performance, powershell, wmi

I am trying to get a PowerShell script to give me the network card name, mac and current usage. Below is my semi working concept. I am just not sure how to match The usage with the other side.

```
$NetworkCards = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
Foreach ($Card in $NetworkCards) {
    if ($Card.NetworkInterfaceType -eq "Ethernet") {
        $Statistics = $null
        Write-Host "Name: " $Card.Name
        Write-Host "Mac: " $Card.GetPhysicalAddress()
        $Statistics = $Card.GetIPv4Statistics()
        $Statistics
        #$BytesTotalPersec = $Statistics.BytesTotalPersec
        #$CurrentBandwidth = $Statistics.CurrentBandwidth
        #$Math = (($BytesTotalPersec*8)/$CurrentBandwidth)*100
        #$Math = [Math]::Round($Math,2)
        #Write-Host $Math

    }

}
```

I know GetIPvStatistics is wrong. I would in a perfect world like to get the data from Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface

Comment: Match usage with the other side? What side is that?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use that WMI class?

```
PS> $data = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormatteData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface | 
                Where {$_.Name -match 'Ethernet'}
PS> $data.BytesTotalPersec
28388
```

Comment: I originally was using that exact wmi class. But the issue is I can't find a way to determine which card is being shown. I have a 4 nic server and it will say "Intel Pro Model #" for all 4 of them. No mac, ID, or actual name. I need a way to identify which card I am getting bytestotalpersec for.